# Error calling webservice restful from senchatouch

Tags: java, javascript, rest, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I took several days trying to solve this problem but no way.

**I want to make a request to a restful webservice that I created in java from a web app I created with senchatouch 2.0.** I researched it to make a request **cross-domain the only option is to use "Ext.data.JsonP.request**". I have taken this **code example**:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
        url: 'http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        params: {
            key: '23f6a0ab24185952101705',
            q: '94301', // Palo Alto
            format: 'json',
            num_of_days: 5
        },
        callback: function( data ) { console.log("callback" + data);},
        success: function(result, request) {
           console.log("success");
           var weather = result.data.weather;
           this.respuesta = 'The temperature in Palo Alto is <b>' + weather[0].tempMaxF + '° F</b>';
           return 'The temperature in Palo Alto is <b>' + weather[0].tempMaxF + '° F</b>';
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            console.log("failure");
            var json = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            return 'fail';
        }

    });
```

**This works perfect. Now I need to connect to my RESTful webservice I created with java (JAX-RS). This is my method:**

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public String getJson(@QueryParam("texto") String cadenaTxt) {
    System.out.println(" -----request in getJson:"+ cadenaTxt + "-----");
    String json1 = "{'name:'George Koch', 'age':58}";
    String jsonPoutput = "callback("+ json1 + ");";
    return jsonPoutput;
}
```

**JavaScript code to make the web service request is:**

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/proxySimplext/webresources/simplificar',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        params: {
            format: 'json',
            texto: 'texto que envio'
        },
        callback: function( data ) { 
            console.log("callback" + data);
        },
        success: function(result, request) {
           console.log("success");
           return 'Sucesss';
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            console.log("failure");
            var json = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            console.log('Fallo de conexion:' + json);
            return 'failure';
        }

    });
```

**NOT working.**

The request comes to the web service but skips a **timeout in JavaScript code**. I have tried many solutions but there is no way to fix it.

The response on the console is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 
failure Utils.js:105
Fallo de conexion:undefined
```

What could happen? Any idea is welcome to give me

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Since the *failure* handler is getting fired, I suspect the issue is with your webservice itself. I would look at your server app's logging to see what it's choking on. Sometimes it's also helpful to debug the webservice by hitting it directly...that way, you don't have the extra layer of Sencha Touch to have to troubleshoot.

Comment: I imagine the issue is that the webservice is not configured to correctly intake the construction of the url that Sencha Touch is sending.